# Recurring in Authorization & Capture

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I managed to make an authorized payment using Authorization & Capture API.

1. SetExpressCheckout with PAYMENTREQUEST_n_PAYMENTACTION=Authorization
2. GetExpressCheckoutDetails to get PAYERID and other information
3. DoExpressCheckoutPayment with PAYMENTREQUEST_n_PAYMENTACTION=Authorization
4. DoCapture with AUTHORIZATIONID={transactionID_from_step_3}

Everything works fine. But, I unable to perform doAuthorization and DoReauthorization for the next time. I wish to charge my subscribers recurring every month. A few attempts have been tried. Does anyone know how to perform Authorization & Capture recurring? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

PS: Sorry for my broken English.

Comment: why can't you use https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/

Comment: @techycommerce my subscribers are charged by variable amounts instead of fixed amounts every month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An authorization is an agreement to pay for one bundle of goods. Once that authorized transaction is completed the authorization is consumed/used up. You cannot use it (alone) for multiple transaction payments.

You need to use the Reference Transaction product, which is how PayPal collects the user's agreement for you to make (current and) future transactions:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/